# My formula is slightly off for calculating Tax in Excel. It's messing up the rest of my values

Tags: excel-formula

I have the following homework problem for excel. Tax ($):

> - Use a formula to determine the dollar amount of the tax.
> - The tax rate is found in cell B2.
> - Tax is applied to the phone (less the discount), AppleCare+, and the activation fee.

I currently have

```
=SUM(H11,K11)*B$2
```

This returns an output but the check figure for M28 should be $1,142.63. The previous column formulas should be correct so I don't think its those that is throwing it off.

H11 Formula is

```
=IF(G11=TRUE,SUM(F11,B$1),F11)
```

K11 Formula is

```
=VLOOKUP(E11,Activation!$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE)
```

Check Figures:

```
I20 = 5%    
J16 = ($101.88)    
M28 = $1,142.63    
N13 = VIP    
N24 = Regular    
K5 = $744.44
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the tax rate is in `B2`, why does your formula reference `B12`?

Comment: That was just a typo error. I do have B$2 in my formula and it's still off by a bit.

Comment: No probs, Buddy, here's some other things you can do to make the solution easier to figure out. 1/ Provide an image with the rows as well, so lazy people like me don't have to count them - for anyone else having trouble `11` is the first row of data. 2/ Make sure you're not in edit mode for `K11` so we can see the value going in there. 3/ Show us the `Activation` sheets so we can check what the `vlookup` is actually doing. Any of those (and preferably all) will go a long way toward helping us help you.

Comment: okay sounds good, will do.

Answer (score 0):

> Tax is applied to the phone ***(less the discount),*** AppleCare+, and the activation fee.

Your formula (which I believe you posted *incorrectly* as `=SUM(H28,K28)*B$2` since it generates the wrong data so I've used what I *think* you're using based on the value generated):

```
=SUM(H28,K28)*B$2-J28  => (1078 + 25) + 8.25% = 1194.00 - 47.45 = 1146.55
```

does not take into account the "less the discount" phrase, it should instead be:

```
=SUM(H28,K28,J28)*B$2  => (1078 + 25 - 47.45) + 8.25% = 1142.63
```

The first figure matches what you're seeing in your spreadsheet, the second matches what the check value says it should be. The bottom line is that you're erroneously applying tax to the value *before* the discount, it should be applied *after* the discount.

It's bad enough we have to give those tax collectors anything at *all,* we certainly don't want to be giving them more than necessary :-)

Comment: something else must be off then because the Check figure for M28 still isn't correct.

Comment: @Buddy, see the update. If you use the formula I posted, it should give the correct result.